# Using fork() incorrectly?

Tags: c, linux, fork

I'm trying to use fork() to implement a message queue. Here's what I've got.

```
#define DATA_SIZE 256
#define BUFF_SIZE 4096

int main(void) {
    // seed the random number generator
    srand(time(NULL));

    // Parent and Ground Truth Buffers
    char ground_truth[BUFF_SIZE]    = {0};  // used to verify
    char producer_buffer[BUFF_SIZE] = {0};  // used by the parent
    int i = 0;  
    int msqid = 0;
    int rc;
    pid_t msq_pid;

    for (i = 0; i < BUFF_SIZE; ++i) {
        producer_buffer[i] = ground_truth[i] = rand() % 256;
    }

    const key_t s_msq_key = 1337;  // used to create message queue ipc
    const char *const p_msq_key = "/OS_MSG";

    msqid = msgget(s_msq_key, IPC_CREAT | 0660);

    msq_pid = fork();

    if(msq_pid == -1){
       perror("error forking");
       exit(1);
    }

    if(msq_pid > 0){
        rc = msgsnd(msqid, (void*)p_msq_key, sizeof(producer_buffer), 0);
        printf("MESSAGE SENT\n");
        if(rc < 0){
            perror("message send failed");
            exit(1);
        }
        return 1;
    } else {
        if(memcmp(producer_buffer, ground_truth, DATA_SIZE) == 0){
            printf("MESSAGE REC");
            return 1;
        }
        exit(1);
    }

return 0;
}
```

I added my actual problem. Hopefully this isn't too much. This is a homework assignment but I didn't want to just get help with the code. Once again, the only result that I am getting is `MESSAGE REC` rather than `MESSAGE SENT` followed by `MESSAGE REC`

EDIT:

Okay, I added an error check for `msq_pid == -1`. I also noticed that when I restarted my Virtual Machine, I was able to get both `MESSAGE SENT` and `MESSAGE REC`. After several more runs of the program, I then began only receiving `MESSAGE REC`. Can someone explain this?

Comment: Post a short but entire program which we can compile that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: If that code is in `main`, it should work (although you should have `\n` at the end of the first `printf`). If you moved it to a subroutine, then you haven't shown enough code.

Comment: I edited the problem to include all of my logic.

Comment: fork can return 0, a positive pid, or -1 (with `errno` set). You're only handling two of three cases, and treating the first and third the same. I don't know if that's your problem, but when debugging, first make sure you have your error checks covered :)

Comment: Got it! Checking for all three cases. I added an edit explain a little further. When I restart my machine I receive the appropriate `SENT` followed by `REC`, but when I run it multiple times it eventually just returns `REC`

Comment: Sending a 7 byte message and then telling `msgsnd()` that it's 4,096 bytes long seems like an obvious error. The second argument to `msgsnd()` should be a pointer to a `struct`, unless you're sending a zero length message. Your problem is likely that `msgsnd()` is crashing before `"MESSAGE SENT"` has a chance to be output. You should read the manual page for `msgsnd()`.

Comment: Ah! What an obvious error. You're definitely right. I need to figure out how to do it correctly, but after removing the `sizeof(producer_buffer)` it no longer crashes and I am getting `SENT` followed by `REC`

Comment: the 'edited' posted code fails to compile.  This is mostly because the `#include` statements are missing.

Comment: Note:  `fork()` has nothing to do with implementing a message queue.

Answer (score 2):

Per the [fork()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fork.html) man page it seems your problem is that you have the child and parent inverted. fork() returns 0 to the child process, it returns > 0 to the parent, and  returns -1 on error. So in your code you should have:

```
if(msg_pqid == 0) { 
     /* The child sends the message */ 
} else { 
    /* Parent receives the message */ 
}
```

I prefer to use a switch like so:

```
switch ((msg_pqid = fork())) {
case -1: 
    /* Error */
case 0:
    /* Child sends message */
default:
    /* Parent receives message */
}
```

Comment: not the root of the problem.   The child fails to call `msgrcv()` and some parameters to msgget() and msgsnd() are not correct.

Comment: You are correct it is not the root of the problem. But as he states that this is a homework problem. I decided to just address his doubts on his use of `fork()` with that uncertainty eliminated he could concentrate on finding the root of the problem on his own.

Answer (score 0):

several of the system calls are being used incorrectly.

The returned status from several of the system calls are being ignored

The following code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. performs the desired operation
3. handles all the error conditions

now, the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <time.h>    //time()

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>

#include <unistd.h>  //fork()

#include <string.h>  //memcmp()


#define MAX_MSG_LEN (10)
#define ACT_MSG_LEN (8)

// Parent and Ground Truth Buffers
struct msgbuf
{
    long mtype;       /* message type, must be > 0 */
    char mtext[ MAX_MSG_LEN ];    /* message data */
};

struct msgbuf ground_truth;  // used to verify
struct msgbuf producer_buffer = {1,"message"}; // used by the parent

int main(void)
{
    // seed the random number generator
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));



    //int i = 0;
    int msqid = 0;
    int rc;
    pid_t msq_pid;
    ssize_t rcvStatus;

    const key_t s_msq_key = 1337;  // used to create message queue ipc
    //const char *const p_msq_key = "/OS_MSG";

    msqid = msgget(s_msq_key, IPC_CREAT | 0660);
    if( -1 == msqid )
    {// then msgget failed
        perror( "msgget failed");
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, msgget successful

    msq_pid = fork();

    while(1)
    {
        switch( msq_pid )
        {
            case -1:
                perror("error forking");
                exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
                break;

            default:  // parent process
                rc = msgsnd(msqid, &producer_buffer, sizeof producer_buffer, 0);
                printf("MESSAGE SENT: %s\n", producer_buffer.mtext);
                if(rc < 0)
                {
                    perror("message send failed");
                    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
                }
                break;

            case 0:   // child process
                rcvStatus = msgrcv( msqid, &ground_truth, sizeof( ground_truth ), 0, 0);
                if( -1 == rcvStatus )
                { // then msgrcv failed
                    perror( "msgrcv failed" );
                    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
                }

                // implied else, msgrcv successful

                if(memcmp(producer_buffer.mtext, ground_truth.mtext, ACT_MSG_LEN) == 0)
                {
                    printf("MESSAGE REC %s\n", ground_truth.mtext);
                }

                else
                {
                    printf( "msg Sent: '%s' does not match msg Recv: '%s'\n", producer_buffer.mtext, ground_truth.mtext);
                }
                break;
        } // end switch
    } // end while forever
} // end function: main
```